# "null" in Java drawImage()

Tags: java, graphics, drawimage

I mean the drawImage() method is not working for me. People say to do like

```
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
```

But eclipse actually deny it. It said:

> The method drawImage(Image, int, int, ImageObserver) in the type Graphics is not applicable for the arguments (Image, int, int, null)

This actually make my really confused, I have read some answers from others, which they always say to put it to null.
I tried to run it, and it give me this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method drawImage(Image, int, int, ImageObserver) in the type Graphics is not applicable for the arguments (Image, int, int, null)

at me.danielshe.graphics.DrawComponent.paintComponent(DrawComponent.java:29)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone help me, or is that a way to put something instead of "null"? I have tried to put "this" and even implementing the ImageObserver. But neither of them works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need an object that implements the ImageObserver interface.  Normally
this is would be the component associated with the graphics object.

Comment: I mean... I stated out that I tried to implement the ImageObserver, it can implement but when I write "this" to replace "null", it still does not work...

Comment: if "this" doesn't work, then it isn't an ImageObserver.  Just to get off ground zero, use new Component()

Answer (score 0):

Using null as an ImageObserver it's not wrong. Is equivalent to this:

```
ImageObserver obs = null;
drawImage( img, x , y , obs );
```

Null can be used anywhere you would use a reference (Object). The problem arises when you need to use this reference/object, you will get a runtime exception as the object would be empty. In your example as long as your image is fully loaded when you call drawImage(), you won't have a problem, therefore you should only use null on drawImage() if you know for sure that your image is fully loaded. Now I haven't had this problem with the compiler, but I don't use eclipse, just a text editor and the command line. Try compiling with the command line or use the two lines of code from above on eclipse.

"this" will only work if the class where you are using drawImage implements the ImageObserver interface or if it extends a class that implements it, like a Jcomponent for example.